# How to check scrollview, scrolled 3 times the size of the screen in Android

Tags: android, scrollview

I want to display scroll_up button when scrollview is scrolled 3 times the size of screen. Is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

`ScrollView` has `getScrollY()` method which returns the scroll position of Y coordinate (height).
You can add `scrollView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnScrollChangedListener()`, and compare `getScrollY()` value to the device screen height.

Answer (score 0):

Get the screen size with DisplayMetrics:

```
val metrics = DisplayMetrics()
windowManager.defaultDisplay.getMetrics(metrics)
```

Then check with your ScrollView:

```
scrollView.setOnScrollChangeListener { _, _, scrollY, _, _ ->
    if(scrollY >= metrics.heightPixels*3) {
        // Your code here.
    }
}
```